# Differentiating between Return and numpad Enter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, input, actionscript, air

I am having some trouble working out how to differentiate the <kbd>Return</kbd> key on my keyboard and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key located on the num pad.

I've had success in separating other keys with duplicates, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> by using:

```
if(e.keyLocation == KeyLocation.RIGHT) // is on right side of keyboard

or

if(e.keyLocation == KeyLocation.LEFT) // is on left side of keyboard
```

However, when attempting something similar to separate my <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from my <kbd>Return</kbd> key using:

```
if(e.keyLocation == KeyLocation.NUM_PAD)
```

Flash insists on treating them both like they're from `KeyLocation.Standard` It's also worth mentioning that Flash treats both keys as the exact same key, with the exact same `keyCode` (13) in the same way that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> share the same `keyCode` yet still can't be isolated by `KeyLocation` like they can.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I might solve this issue? Or is this simply a limitation with AS3? Thanks.

**Edit:** It might be worth mentioning that I am developing this to be used with Adobe AIR as a desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, this doesn't seem possible.
After trying it out for myself, numpad_enter always returns KeyLocation = 0 (so it's standard, not left, right or numpad) and returns as keycode 13, the keycode of the return key.

Keyboard.NUMPAD_ENTER is defined as 108 though, but this will never get sent internally by flash when you press the numpad_enter button, it'll simply send the KeyboardEvent with the values of the normal enter button.

You can try asking Adobe to fix this [Adobe HelpCenter](http://forums.adobe.com/community/flashplayer)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, are you trying with standalone FlashPlayer ?
You should try with on your browser.

It can separate with `KeyLocation.NUM_PAD`.

Comment: Sorry. I should probably mention that this project is actually being developed with Adobe AIR in mind for desktop use. I sometimes forget that this may be a factor. I'll edit the main post to include that bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that on the mac, AIR runtime doesn't differentiate between the RETURN and numpad ENTER keys. They produce the identical output, so we are screwed. A rather unfortunate oversight, but nowadays with tiny laptops one doesn't see both keys anyway.